# Why are there two parameter groups in cats Bifunctor[F[_, _]].bimap function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I stumbled upon this problem when trying to implement a Bifunctior type class for maps (`Bifunctor[Map[_, _]]`).

[Bifunctor](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Bifunctor.scala) is defined like this in cats:

```
/**
   * The quintessential method of the Bifunctor trait, it applies a
   * function to each "side" of the bifunctor.
   *
   * Example:
   * {{{
   * scala> import cats.implicits._
   *
   * scala> val x: (List[String], Int) = (List("foo", "bar"), 3)
   * scala> x.bimap(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)
   * res0: (Option[String], Long) = (Some(foo),4)
   * }}}
   */
  def bimap[A, B, C, D](fab: F[A, B])(f: A => C, g: B => D): F[C, D]
```

As the comment states, this function can be called using two functions (in one parameter group) as its input like this: `x.bimap(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)`. This tells me that this is clearly not the `bimap` function being called since this one has two parameter groups (`(fab: F[A, B])(f: A => C, g: B => D)`). I have been wondering if there is some kind of implicit type conversion that I am not aware of happening here. How does it work? What do I need to implement to get a Bifunctor type class for maps?

Comment: Indeed there are implicit conversions happening. For the example from docs we have something like `toBifunctorOps(x)(catsStdBitraverseForTuple2).bimap(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An instance of type class `Bifunctor` for `Map` can be defined as follows

```
implicit val mapBifunctor: Bifunctor[Map] = new Bifunctor[Map] {
  override def bimap[A, B, C, D](fab: Map[A, B])(f: A => C, g: B => D): Map[C, D] = 
    fab.map { case (k, v) => f(k) -> g(v) }
}
```

In `x.bimap(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)` implicits are resolved twice:

- firstly, instance `Bifunctor[Tuple2]` is found (`import cats.instances.tuple._` or `import cats.instances.all._` or `import cats.implicits._`),
- secondly, extension method is resolved (`import cats.syntax.bifunctor._` or `import cats.syntax.all._` or `import cats.implicits._`)

Thus `x.bimap(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)` is transformed to

```
implicitly[Bifunctor[Tuple2]].bimap(x)(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)
```

or

```
Bifunctor[Tuple2].bimap(x)(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)
```

or

```
toBifunctorOps(x)(catsStdBitraverseForTuple2).bimap(_.headOption, _.toLong + 1)
```